# Show $A$ is self-adjoint and $ f= Au$ in weak sense.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, distribution-theory

Hoi, consider $L_2(\Omega)$ with $\Omega = (0,1)\times (0,1)$ and let $u\in L_2(\Omega)$ be defined as

$u(x,y) = 1$ for $x>y$ and $u(x,y) = 0$ for $x\leq y$. Let $A = \partial_x^2 - \partial^2_y$
an operator densely defined on $C_0^{\infty}(\Omega)\subset L_2(\Omega)$

Let $(f,g) = \int_{\Omega}f\overline{g}d\omega$

I want to show that $A' = A $(the adjoint).

Also I want to show that there exists $f\in L_2(\Omega)$ such that $$(f,\phi)= (u,A'\phi) $$ with $Amax f=0$

for all $\phi \in C_0^{\infty}(\Omega)$ so that $f = Au$ in the weak sense. How do we do this? I have an idea of how to do the first part, but in the second one im clueless.

Comment: Are you sure that this is the correct definition of $u$. Because in the form as it is stated, $u=0$ everywhere and then $f=0$.

Comment: Auch. Yes, you're absolutely right. It is $u(x,y)=1$ for $x>y$. I changed it.

Comment: To me it is hard to understand how such $f$ exist..An $f$ that almost takes the role of the operator $A$. So we need to show that there exists $f$ such that $\int_{\Omega} f\overline{\phi}d\omega = \int_{\left\{x>y\right\}}(\partial^2_x-\partial_y^2)\overline{\phi}d\omega$ for all $\phi \in C_0^{\infty}(\Omega)$

Comment: They give as hint: One has to carry out some integrations by parts; it may make the arguments easier to change to new coordinates $s=x+y$, and $t = x-y$. (it is 4.3 from Gerd grubb: Distributions and operators).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $s=x+y$ and $t=x-y$. Note that $x=\frac{s+t}{2}$ and $y=\frac{s-t}{2}$. Write $h(s,t)=\phi(\frac{s+t}{2},\frac{s-t}{2})$ and calculate $\partial^2_{st} h$ to find that $$4\partial^2_{st} h=\partial^2_x\phi-\partial^2_y\phi$$

Substitue it in the expression $\int_{x>y}(\partial^2_x-\partial^2_y)\overline{\phi}$. Now, draw a picture of the new domain of integration, and convince yourself that it is good to do integration by parts with relation to the variable $s$.

Comment: What do u actually mean by $\partial_{st}$, is that differentiating w.r.t. '$st$'?. Im not so good in this stuff.

Comment: $\partial^2_{st}$ mean you derivate in the direction $s$ and then in the direction $t$. In our case it does not matter, because $\partial^2_{st}=\partial^2_{ts}$.

Comment: OK. Hmm...I get the integral  $$4\int_1^0 \int_0^{2-2t}\partial_s²\partial_t²h(s,t)dsdt$$. Hope my integration domain is correct. And apparantly partially integrating the inner-integral helps me seeing it becomes 0?

Comment: It is close, but this is not the domain of integration. The domain of integration is an triangle with vertex in: $(0,0),(1,1),(2,0)$.

Comment: Ok, but after partial integrations we get something like $$\int ([\partial_s\partial_t² h(s,t)]-[s\partial_t² h(s,t)]-\int s²/2\partial_t²h(s,t)ds]) dt $$ evaluated in these domain-values. So I guess we split up the domain in 2 parts ]. But i cant see this being 0.

Comment: No, after integration by part, you wiil get something like this $$\int_0^1\int_{f(t)}^{g(t)}\partial_s\partial_t h(s,t)=-\int_0^1\int_{f(t)}^{g(t)} 0\partial_t h(s,t)+\int_0^1 \partial_t h(\mbox{here is applied on the boundary of the triangle},t)$$

Comment: To do this integration by parts, you set $u=1$ and $dv=\partial_s\partial_t h(s,t)$. Then $du=0ds$ and $dv=\partial_t h(s,t)ds$. Hence, you can use the formula $$\int udv=uv-\int vdu$$

Comment: Ok, so I guess the integral with $\partial_th(s,t)$ evaluated in boundary also becomes 0. But suppose we wouldnt do all these substitutions: Then by doing the same sort of partial integrations like you did we get $$(u,\partial_x^2\phi) =  -\int_0^1\partial_x\phi(y,y)dy$$ and similarly $$(u,\partial_y^2\phi) = \int_0^1\partial_y\phi(x,x)dx$$ Can we see $(u,(\partial_x^2-\partial_y^2)\phi)= 0$ from this also? Also in your integral, do we have to apply another (same sort)  partial integration w.r.t. $t$, or can we see that applying in boundary becomes 0.

Comment: No, $(u,\partial^2_x\phi)=\int_\Omega u\partial^2_x\phi(x,y)=\int_{x>y}\partial^2_x\phi(x,y)$. The problem with this way is that your funcion $\phi$ does not to need to be zero on the boundary of the triangle, i.e. in the set $\{x=y\}$, $\phi$ may be positive or negative., so the boundary term does not vanish

Comment: Ok, thank you kindly for your help.