# Is this integral 0?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, distribution-theory

Let $\phi \in C_0^{\infty}(\Omega)$ with $\Omega = (0,1)\times(0,1)$. Let $u\in L_2(\Omega)$ defined by  $u(x,y) = 1$ for $x>y, u(x,y) = 0$ for $x\leq y$

Is there a way we can conclude $$\int_{\Omega}(\partial_x^2-\partial_y^2)u\phi d\omega =0 $$

using that $\phi$ has compact support?

Comment: What is the meaning of $(\partial^2_x-\partial^2_y)u$? $u$ is not differentiable on $\{x=y\}$.

Comment: I wish I could tell you. I have no idea. :P It arose as part of the other problem u reacted on. We might just as well change the integral to $\int_{x>y}(\partial_x^2-\partial_y^2)\phi d\omega$...

Comment: Can you explain how is the problem stated?

Comment: Ok Let me write down the exact formulation of the problem. However I assume that you are aware of the terminology used.

Comment: Actually its small formulation: Let $u(x,y), C_0^{\infty}(\Omega)$  be like above. $A = \partial_x^2-\partial_y^2$ an operator densely defined on $C_0^{\infty} \subset L_2$. One can easily show by application of Green that $A'=A$ is formally selfadjoint. Show that $u\in D(A_{\max})$, with $A_{\max}u=0$. Here $A_{\max} = (A'|_{C_0^{\infty}(\Omega)})^*$ the adjoint.

Comment: I alread solved this problem for you here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326889/show-a-is-self-adjoint-and-f-au-in-weak-sense . So what is the problem, why do you accepted the naswer if you do not understand it?

Comment: I accept the answer because I appreciate the help. But i have here in fact another question, whether we conclude the integral is 0 in any way.

Comment: Ok, there we show that $(u,A'\phi)=(u,A\phi)=\int_{x>y}A\phi=0$, $\forall\phi C_0^\infty(\Omega)$. This implies that $(u,A'\phi)=(0,\phi)$. Beause of the unicity showed in page 58 of Grubb's book, you can conclude that $A_{\max}u=0$

Comment: Yes, so then we need to show that $\int_{x>y}A\phi =0$ which is the above integral. I am having trouble with this...

Comment: I have showed this in the answer that you accepted.

Comment: Realy? Guess Im just too stupid to understand this ;p

Comment: Take a look there and try to undertand it. If you have any doubt post there that I try to help you.

Answer (score -1):

Notice that $u$ is differentiable almost everywhere, which also follows straightforward from definition.

You have $$\int_{\Omega}\partial_{x}^{2}u\phi=-\int_{\Omega}\partial_{x}u\partial_{x}\phi+\int_{\partial \Omega}\partial_{x}u\phi$$

where the second term vanishes since $\phi$ has compact support. Similarly for $\partial_{y}$. But we know $\partial_{x}u=0$ almost everywhere in $\Omega$ except a measure zero set $x=y$. This showed the summation must be zero.

Comment: Sorry, that doesnt make sense to me. You use Green's formula I believe. But If you apply it another time, and using that the integral over the boundary is zero, we must now show that $$\int_{\Omega}u\partial_{x}^2\phi = 0 $$ it might be true that $\partial_xu = 0$ a.e. but shouldnt we see it as $\partial_x(u\partial_x\phi) = \partial_x u \partial_x\phi + u\partial_x^2\phi$?

Comment: I only want to apply it once, not twice. This is the key to the solution.

Comment: Ok, but like i said...$\partial_x u \partial_x\phi  = \partial_x (u \partial_x\phi)$  right? and not 
$(\partial_xu)(\partial_x\phi)$...or is that a misunderstanding.

Comment: @user32240, what is the realtion between $u\in L^1$ and $u$ being almost everywhere differentiable? Also $\partial_x u$ and $\partial_y u$ does not make sense in all domain.

Comment: @Tomas: I suggest you look up differentials for measurable functions. I may be confused with Lesbegue differentiation theorem.

Comment: @DinkyDoe: Yes you misunderstood.

Comment: That the function $u$ is almost everywhere differentiable I agree, but this has nothing to do with $L^1$. Also, only using the fact that $u$ is almost everywhere differentiable you cant justify the intgration by parts you have used.

Comment: @Tomás: So I deleted the $L^{1}$ part. I use integration by parts by treating $u$ as a distribution, then I can use the fact $C^{0}$ functions is dense in $D'$. Now $u$ is certainly $C^{0}$ almost everywhere.

Comment: Look @user32240. $u\in L^1_{loc}$, so $u$ defined a distribution $T$, by setting $<T,\phi>=\int u\phi$. NOw we can derivate $T$ as a distribtuion and the result (that is not $\partial_x u$) is $\langle\partial_x T,\phi\rangle=-\langle T,\partial_x \phi\rangle$. It does not make sense to say that $\partial_x u$ defines a distribution, because this is not well defined.

Comment: @Tomás: No, I do not use $\partial_{x}u$ as a distribution, I use it as a function. You are confused.

Comment: You can't use it as an function @user32240. It does not make sense.

Comment: @Tomás: I cannot use it directly, but I can approximate it with one. And in particular itself.

Comment: I suggest the downvoter spend sometime to finish the details of my proof. I do not have much energy to debate with people at here.